# Is anyone stacking LSTM and GRU cells together and why?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

TensorFlow allows you to create [MultiRNNCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#MultiRNNCell) composed sequentially of multiple simple cells (LSTM and GRU). I usually use same type of cell when creating [MultiRNNCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#MultiRNNCell) but I was wondering if there could be some benefits in using both LSTM and GRU?
Does anyone have some experience with it or theoretical insights?

Comment: Would be pretty interesting to see. I might be testing the combination of LSTM and NARX cells.

Answer (score 3):

There are some thousands of variants of RNN cell(kernel) and both LSTM and GRU are for processing the input $x_i$ and the output of the previous state $s_{i-1}$, producing the output and the current state. Even though LSTM preceded GRU and GRU involves less computation, LSTM is just on a par with GRU in performance. Therefore, I believe that stacking LSTM and GRU, or any other cells, might be interesting but would not make a significant difference in improving performance when compared to simply stacking either LSTM cells or GRU cells.

As George E. P. Box put it, all models are wrong, but some are useful, you can just have a try to see if it is useful or not.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence: they really don't do things that are that different so there's not that much advantage you'd get from combining them.

Comment: When you say that LSTM is on par with GRU, are you making the comparison on a per-unit basis or a per-parameter basis?