# What is the point of putting two lstm cells one after another?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've seen something like this a lot in literature : "we used x lstms cells in our implementation".
I don't understand the point of using several stacked lstms : indeed, why isn't a single cell enough as it already takes the cell state and the hidden state from the previous time step ?

For example page 4 of this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04928.pdf

I see the advantage of parallelizing two cells but not the one of stacking.

Comment: Your question is automatically flagged as low-quality because it is so short. Can you extend your question please?

Comment: Thank you for extending your question. Now it looks much better. If you still remember the paper where you read this sentence it would be awesome if you provide a link.

Comment: yes no problem, I edited again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One layer only has one cell. For more information read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275518/103153). And the stacked multi-layer LSTM model is for extracting more abstract information. I think [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-for-LSTM-to-be-multilayer) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179817/103153) have explained this issue in detail.

Comment: Also might want to point to Graves' [seminal paper on stacked LSTMs for speech recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5778.pdf): "If LSTM is used for the hidden layers we get
deep bidirectional LSTM, the main architecture used in this
paper. As far as we are aware this is the first time *deep* LSTM
has  been applied  to  speech  recognition,  and we  find  that it
yields a dramatic improvement over single-layer LSTM." ([Graves et al., 2013](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6638947/))