# Stacking recurrent neural network layers horizontally vs vertically

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In the top answer on this post: [What are the advantages of stacking multiple LSTMs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163304/what-are-the-advantages-of-stacking-multiple-lstms) the idea of stacking LSTMs vertically is distinguished from stacking
them horizontally. I quite don't understand what this means.
When I think of stacking LSTMs, I think of having the output of
one LSTM layer going into another LSTM layer. Would this be vertical or
horizontal stacking?

To me that is the only way the word "stacking" makes sense. If you
had two layers side by side (like with bidirectional
layers which are technically just two separate layers whose outputs
are concatenated or averaged) then it doesn't make much sense to
call them "stacked".

What is the other form of stacking, other than feeding one layer into another? And in what cases should you use one type of stacking vs the other?